# Exercise about how to study the behavior of an integral function?

Tags: calculus

I have this integral:

$$\int_a^ye^{-t}(t-2)dt$$
And I have to study the behavior of this integral at varying of $y_{0}$

----> $a$ means $y_{0}$

and $y$ without solving it with classic rules.

For example I can say:

if $y_{0}>2$ and $y\rightarrow\infty$ the integral diverges to $+\infty$.

This is pretty correct on the solutions but I'm very confused.

Wich is the relations used to write this statement? How is related the integrand function with his primitive to estimate if the integral diverges or not?

Thank you, I know that maybe is not so clear, but maybe someone expert will understand my question. Thank you :)

Comment: What do you mean by "classic rules"?

Comment: Hi,I mean computing the integral (maybe using "for parts" rules). The point is that I don't need the primitive but only know the behavior of the integral.

Comment: The integral is finite when $y_0>2$, even $y\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Maybe you can consider the function $$f(a,b)=\int_a^b e^{-t}(t-2)dt .$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think that I must consider the function you wrote, but I need some help to justify the steps: in this way I could have the proof that I've understand the point. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{split}
\int_{y_0}^ye^{-t}(t-2)\mathrm{d}t=&-\int_{y_0}^y(t-2)\mathrm{d}e^{-t} \\
=&-(t-2)e^{-t}\bigg|_{y_0}^y+\int_{y_0}^ye^{-t}\mathrm{d}(t-2) \\
=&-(t-2)e^{-t}\bigg|_{y_0}^y+\int_{y_0}^ye^{-t}\mathrm{d}t \\
=&-(t-2)e^{-t}\bigg|_{y_0}^y-e^{-t}\bigg|_{y_0}^y \\
=&-(t-1)e^{-t}\bigg|_{y_0}^y \\
=&-(y-1)e^{-y}+(y_0-1)e^{-y_0}
\end{split}$$
So if $y_0>2, y\rightarrow+\infty$, the answer is $e^{-2}$.
I'm not sure I have solved your problem. And I don't understand "classic rules".

Comment: Thank you for your reply! You have solved the integral (whit the classic rules I mean). My point is: there is a way to know the behavior of the integral withoud complete solving it? 
Because this is an integral which became after separation of variables in an ODE and I have to draw a qualitative graph. Thank you :)